# hide rows excel vba does not work when not triggered

Tags: excel, rows, hidden, vba

I have a macro that works perfectly well when triggered on an onchange event.  It simply checks a cell value and hides or unhides rows elsewhere on the same active sheet.  Here is the macro that hides or unhides rows:

```
Sub ToggleTaskTable()

MsgBox "Toggling Tasks"

        If Cells(56, 3).Value = "No" Then
            Cells(57, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = 
            MsgBox "Hding Rows 106, 148 and 190"

            ActiveSheet.Rows("106").Hidden = True
            ActiveSheet.Rows("148").Hidden = True
            ActiveSheet.Rows("190").Hidden = True

' try it another way

            Rows("106").Hidden = True
            Rows("148").Hidden = True
            Rows("190").Hidden = True

        Else
            Cells(57, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False

           '  MsgBox "Showing task Rows 106, 148 and 190"

            Rows("106").Hidden = False
            Rows("148").Hidden = False
            Rows("190").Hidden = False
       End If
End Sub
```

If I call the macro as a result of changing a cell `C56` to "No", it works perfectly.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Address = "$C$56" Then
      Call ToggleTaskTable
   End If
End Sub
```

If I call the macro from another macro, with `C56` set to "No", it does not work at all.

```
Sub CallAllMacros()
   Call ToggleTaskTable
End Sub
```

Even though the msgbox shows indicating it is hiding the rows, it does not actually hide them.

I am totally stumped!

Comment: I think you need to fully qualify your Objects and re-write your code. [You can start here on ways on how to do that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ToggleTaskTable()
    With ActiveSheet
        .Range("A57,A106,A148,A190").EntireRow.Hidden = (.Cells(56, 3).Value = "No")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is much more eloquent than my new-be code, but did not solve the problem.  My code had worked fine apparently, I had some subsequent code that re-unhid the rows.  Duh!  Thanks so much anyway :)